# Marker with Textinput in Flutter

Tags: flutter, marker

How can i add a marker on Google Maps in Flutter, where the User can change the Title and the snippet. It should be a User input, but i dont know how to do this. In this code, the user is able to set a marker by long press on the map. But the Info widget is only the text i choosed befor in the code. (How can i change my code, that the user is able to set a marker, than a window open and the user is able to typ a title and a snipet in it. After closing the window the marker have the Title and snipet from the user.) This is just an idea !!!

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:location/location.dart';


GoogleMapController mapController;

class MapsDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  MapsDemo() : super();



  @override
  MapsDemoState createState() => MapsDemoState();
}

class MapsDemoState extends State<MapsDemo> {
  //


  Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();
  static const LatLng _center = const LatLng(51, 10);
  List<Marker> _markers = [];
  LatLng _lastMapPosition = _center;
  MapType _currentMapType = MapType.normal;



  void _currentLocation() async {
    final GoogleMapController controller = await _controller.future;
    LocationData currentLocation;
    var location = new Location();
    try {
      currentLocation = await location.getLocation();
    } on Exception {
      currentLocation = null;
    }

    controller.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
      CameraPosition(
        bearing: 0,
        target: LatLng(currentLocation.latitude, currentLocation.longitude),
        zoom: 18.0,
      ),
    ));
  }

  _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
    _controller.complete(controller);
  }

  _onCameraMove(CameraPosition position) {
    _lastMapPosition = position.target;
  }

  _onMapTypeButtonPressed() {
    setState(() {
      _currentMapType = _currentMapType == MapType.normal
          ? MapType.hybrid
          : MapType.normal;
    });
  }

  Future _addMarkerLongPressed(LatLng latlang) async {
    setState(() {
      final MarkerId markerId = MarkerId("RANDOM_ID");
      Marker marker = Marker(
        markerId: markerId,
        draggable: true,
        position: latlang, //With this parameter you automatically obtain latitude and longitude
        infoWindow: InfoWindow(
          title: 'This is a Marker',
          snippet: 'This looks good',
        ),
        icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker,
      );
      markers[markerId] = marker;

    });

    //This is optional, it will zoom when the marker has been created
    GoogleMapController controller = await _controller.future;
    controller.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newLatLngZoom(latlang, 18.0));
  }

  Widget button(Function function, IconData icon) {
    return FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: function,
      materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.padded ,
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      child: Icon(
        icon,
        size: 36.0,
      ),
    );
  }

  Map<MarkerId, Marker> markers = <MarkerId, Marker>{};
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(

      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
        appBar: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(40),

            child: AppBar(

              automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
              centerTitle: true,
              title:  Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  const Text("Viewist", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 35.0),textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
                  const Text("", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 8.0),textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
                ],
              ),
              flexibleSpace: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    gradient: LinearGradient(
                        begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                        end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                        colors: <Color>[
                          Colors.greenAccent,
                          Colors.blueAccent
                        ])
                ),

              ),
            ),

        ),
        body:
        Stack(

            children: [Container(
              padding: new EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                child: GoogleMap(
                  mapType: _currentMapType,
                  onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
                  onCameraMove: _onCameraMove,
                  myLocationEnabled: true,
                  myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
                  initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                    target: _center,
                    zoom: 6.0,
                  ),
                  compassEnabled: true,
                  tiltGesturesEnabled: false,
                  onLongPress: (latlang) {
                    _addMarkerLongPressed(latlang); //we will call this function when pressed on the map
                  },
                  markers: Set<Marker>.of(markers.values), //all markers are here
                ),
            ),


            Padding(

              padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    button(_onMapTypeButtonPressed, Icons.map),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 18.0,
                    ),
                    button(_currentLocation, Icons.location_searching),
                  ],
                ),

              ),
            ),
            ],
        ),
        drawer: Drawer(
          child: ListView(
              padding: new EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
            children: <Widget>[
              DrawerHeader(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      gradient: LinearGradient(colors: <Color>[
                        Colors.green,
                        Colors.lightBlueAccent
                      ])
                  ),
                  child: Container(
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Material(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(40.0)),
                          elevation: 10,
                          child: Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: Image.asset('images/a.png',width: 80,height: 80,),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0), child: Text ('Viewist', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 30.0,),
                        )
                        )],
                    ),
                  )),
              CustomListTile(Icons.person, 'Profile', ()=>{}),
              CustomListTile(Icons.notifications, 'Notification', ()=>{}),
              CustomListTile(Icons.settings, 'Settings', ()=>{}),
              CustomListTile(Icons.lock, 'Log Out', ()=>{}),
            ],
          ),
        ),

      ),

    );
  }

}


  class CustomListTile extends StatelessWidget {
  IconData icon;
  String text;
  Function onTap;

  CustomListTile(this.icon,this.text,this.onTap);

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      // TODO: implement createState
      return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8.0, 0, 8.0, 0),
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border(bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey.shade400))
          ),
          child: InkWell(
            splashColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
            onTap: onTap,
            child: Container(
              height: 50,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Icon(icon),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Text(text, style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 16.0
                        ),),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Icon(Icons.arrow_right)
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );

    }


  }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can display a dialog when the user presses long on the map and ask him to enter the title of his marker.
Once the title is received, you close the dialog and add the marker.

Here is an example:

Google maps widget with showDialog function in onTap function

```dart
GoogleMap(
  // other properties here
  markers: Set<Marker>.of(_markers),
  onTap: (point) => addMarker(point) // edited
)
```

Dialog widget with TextField, return data when dialog closed

```dart
class FormDialog extends StatefulWidget {
  FormDialog({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _FormDialogState createState() => _FormDialogState();
}

class _FormDialogState extends State<FormDialog> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: TextField(
        onSubmitted: (value) => Navigator.pop(context, value),
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: 'Tape title of marker'
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

add function to widget class

```dart
Future<void> addMarker(LatLng point) async {
  var title = await showDialog<String>(
    barrierDismissible: true,
    context: context,
    builder: (context) => FormDialog(),
  );
  if (title != null) {
    setState(() {
      _markers.add(
        Marker(
          markerId: MarkerId('someId'),
          position: point,
          infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: title)
        )
      );
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: It doesent work. If i implement the code its says: error: The argument type 'Future<Null> Function()' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(LatLng)'. (argument_type_not_assignable at [map2] lib\homepage.dart:152)

Comment: how can i improve that?

Comment: the "onTap" function in the GoogleMap widget expects to receive a simple function that returns nothing and before that we returned an asynchronous function. I've edited my answer, can you please test it and tell me if it works. If it doesn't, tell me, I will take the time to test and correct it.